# Include CRS information in GeoJSON features created by OpenLayer's GeoJSON format class?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, geojson

I am using OpenLayers' `format/GeoJSON` class to write features as GeoJSON feature objects. The target CRS is UTM 32, so I use the `dataProjection` option to transform the  geometries from web mercator, but it doesn't seem to add the CRS information to the actual output features.

```js
import { register } from "ol/proj/proj4.js"
import proj4 from "proj4"
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON.js"
import { Projection } from "ol/proj.js"

proj4.defs(
  "EPSG:25832",
  "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
)
register(proj4)
const GeoJsonWriter = new GeoJSON({
  dataProjection: new Projection({ code: "EPSG:25832" }),
  featureProjection: "EPSG:3857",
})

const feat = {
  type: "Feature",
  geometry: {
    type: "Point",
    crs: {
      type: "name",
      properties: {
        name: "EPSG:25832",
      },
    },
    coordinates: [414039.613, 5531087.119],
  },
  properties: {},
}

const ol_feat = GeoJsonWriter.readFeature(feat)
console.log(GeoJsonWriter.writeFeature(ol_feat))

// {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[414039.6129999994,5531087.119]},"properties":null}
```

Am I missing some option that would let me include crs information in the output?

I am using OpenLayers v7.1.0.

Comment: The OpenLayers source https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/format/GeoJSON.js contains no code to writes a CRS.  Instead of `writeFeature` you could use `writeFeatureObject`, add the CRS yourself, then stringify the result.

Comment: GeoJSON (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) only has one CRS.~ `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84`

Comment: But still there are ways to add crs members to GeoJSON, e.g. in PostGIS: the documentation warns that the geometry should be in 4326, but st_asgeojson still adds a crs member if that is not the case (see https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html)

Comment: While waiting some official JSON specification that supports different CRS the best option in my mind is to use the deprecated 2008 specification https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for this, I didn't know it actually used to be part of the spec!